# Custom JSON Serializer for restful wcf

Tags: json, web-services, wcf, rest, serialization

I have a restful wcf ,my method returns a object that contains date time. 
but it fails when the value is DateTime.MinVal

The problem occurs when CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset is > 0  So if I set my time zone to Berlin (+1:00) or beyond, it will return a positive number which means that tickcount will return a negative number since value.Ticks == 0 (minValue), resulting in the exception.

The exception thrown by serializer.WriteObject() is:

Message=***"DateTime values that are greater than DateTime.MaxValue or smaller than DateTime.MinValue when converted to UTC cannot be serialized to JSON."***

**My Question: Is it possible to use other\custom  JSON Serializer ?**

```
 <ServiceContract(Namespace:="XXX")> _
Public Interface IsvcAppUser
           <OperationContract()>
            <FaultContract(GetType(QFlowAPISecurityException))>
            <FaultContract(GetType(QFlowAPIApplicationException))>
            <WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)>
            Function GetMyResourceCalendars() As List(Of CalendarInfo)
End Interface

<DataContract()> _
    Public Class CalendarInfo
        Inherits ObjectBase

        Private _FirstVacancy As DateTime

        <DataMember()> _
        Public Property FirstVacancy() As DateTime
            Get
                Return _FirstVacancy
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As DateTime)
                _FirstVacancy = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
```